# 1 pole switch with one wire backstabbing the bottom andnone feeding to same terminal

Tags: electrical, wiring

So I have a switch with 1 wire backstabbing the same terminal that has a wire wrapped around the screw on the bottom , and I have a ground wire feeding to the ground screw ,and one wire on the  top terminal , and on my new one pole switch i cannot backstab it like it was with the old switch cause theres no tiny hole to do that. What do I do?

Comment: Can you [edit] in a picture of your new switch?

Answer (score 6):

Backstab holes/connections usually not recommended to use.  They tend to be a source of problems later.

Pigtailling(connecting with a wire nut or wago) the two wires with a short one to the screw is recommended.

Some of the better quality switches/receptacles do allow two wires on a screw if they use clamp type holders.

Recent electrical code requires the use of torque driver to set the proper torque on the screws.  They make torque screwdrivers for this.

Comment: _Highly_ recommend returning the cheap switch and getting a "spec grade" switch that has "side clamps". These are the ones that allow 2 wires per screw - installation is _almost_ as easy as the back stab, but includes the security of actually tightening the screw down. Cheaper than buying a box of wire nuts/Wagos (recommend the Wago if you're going that way) and works as well.

Comment: *Possible* that the questioner has the right sort of switch but doesn't know how to use it correctly (we have no pictures, and most folk see a screw and assume it's screw-wrap, without even *looking* at the directions.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Real he-men don't read directions, mainly because they left their reading glasses in the other room.